# How do I add an extension to NetLogo 5.2.1

Tags: netlogo

Can someone point me to documentation for how to install an extension such as Rnd for Version 5.2 of NetLogo?    Here's why I think I need to do that.

I am trying to use a model created in NetLogo 5.2 and I would like to get it to run in version 6.1.1.   I've never done this sort of thing before, so I may be missing something obvious.

If I try to open the model in 6.1.1 the automatic conversion process fails due to a syntax error ( missing parenthesis) and does not un-grey the option to continue to convert it.   So I figured, ok,  I would download Netlogo 5.2 and open the file with that and fix the syntax error, then try the automated conversion again.  So I located and downloaded NetLogo 5.2, the version with bundled java.

The model opens the code fine with NetLogo 5.2, but it requires the Rnd extension, which it doesn't have installed. (I double-checked and there is no Rnd folder in the extensions folder for version 5.2, but other extension folders are there. )  I'd prefer to get that extension so I can actually run the model to confirm I didn't break something else, or at least have the syntax checker work and not get stuck on the missing extension.

Here I become unclear about what I need to do, as NetLogo 5.2 doesn't have a nice tools/extensions... menu choice, so I believe I need to obtain this extension from github myself somehow. I didn't find exact documentation on how to do that.  Here I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

Anyway, I read what documentation I could find and believed that I need to obtain the Rnd.jar file manually and put it into the Rnd folder in the extensions folder, and I'd be good to go.  Perhaps that is incorrect.

In any case, I looked on github at https://github.com/NetLogo/Rnd-Extension and there is no Rnd.jar file that I can find there.  So "punting" fails and I need to find actual documentation or advice.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you try any of the releases from GitHub?  Anything before "Hexy Pre Release" (the 6.0 release) might have a shot at working:  https://github.com/NetLogo/Rnd-Extension/releases

Comment: I did try just copying the rnd file from netlogo 6.1.1 into the rnd folder for netlogo 5.2, but the system complained that the extension was for the wrong version and wouldn't let me continue.

Comment: hmm.   I tried v1.1.0 of the extension, but winzip complained that the files were corrupt.  Not sure what that's about,as surely they worked once. I'll try again later.

Comment: OK, I tried again with Winzip, but unzipped to a different folder -- apparently windows 10 thought the extensions folder required authorization and even though I said ok it failed.  I unloaded to "temp" instead and it worked and I can work now!

Answer (score 0):

Jasper suggested the following,

> Did you try any of the releases from GitHub? Anything before "Hexy Pre
>   Release" (the 6.0 release) might have a shot at working:
>   github.com/NetLogo/Rnd-Extension/releases – Jasper

and I got version v1.1.0 of the extension downloaded, unzipped, putting the rnd.jar file into the new rnd folder in the extensions folder, 
and everything worked.

Thank you Jasper!